# Possible disk failure. Should I be worried?

Tags: hard-drive, drive-failure, smartmontools

I think our HDD is failing. 
Before I dump all the relevant logs: don't worry, everything is backed up daily, HDD can be replaced. I just need to confirm my suspicions.
HDD is in raid so there is another disk and (as you can see) this server is online 24/7 for past 2+ years.

Smartctl reported Error 348 reported at 19677h which match error in syslog. 
Same thing for 349-351.

This drive is dying, right?

Logs:

```
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716010.818934] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x3ffff SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716010.862259] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716010.904504] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716010.946338] ata1.00: cmd 60/80:00:00:84:49/00:00:0b:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 65536 in
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716010.946338]          res 41/40:80:78:84:49/00:00:0b:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.110653] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.151079] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324910] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324938] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324941] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324943] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324944] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324946] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324949] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324951]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324957]         0b 49 84 78 
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324960] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324963] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324965] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324967] Read(10): 28 00 0b 49 84 00 00 00 80 00
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.324973] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 189367416
Nov  9 02:50:04 XXXXX kernel: [21716011.364405] ata1: EH complete
Nov  9 02:50:24 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.325428] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1e000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Nov  9 02:50:24 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.367450] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Nov  9 02:50:24 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.408335] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  9 02:50:24 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.448762] ata1.00: cmd 60/80:68:00:86:49/00:00:0b:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq 65536 in
Nov  9 02:50:24 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.448762]          res 41/40:80:18:86:49/00:00:0b:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Nov  9 02:50:24 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.607084] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Nov  9 02:50:24 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.645924] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967600] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967616] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967619] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967621] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967624] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967626] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967629] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967631]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967640]         0b 49 86 18 
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967644] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967647] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967650] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967652] Read(10): 28 00 0b 49 86 00 00 00 80 00
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716031.967660] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 189367832
Nov  9 02:50:25 XXXXX kernel: [21716032.005452] ata1: EH complete
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.237709] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x380 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.272985] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.307238] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.341080] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:38:00:92:49/04:00:0b:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq 524288 in
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.341080]          res 41/40:00:08:95:49/00:04:0b:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.473214] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.505636] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572423] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572453] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572457] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572459] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572462] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572464] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572467] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572469]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572478]         0b 49 95 08 
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572482] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572485] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572488] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572489] Read(10): 28 00 0b 49 92 00 00 04 00 00
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.572498] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 189371656
Nov  9 02:50:41 XXXXX kernel: [21716048.603930] ata1: EH complete
```

After seeing that did smartctl -a /dev/sda . Here is the log:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-36-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1500DM003-9YN16G
Serial Number:    W2F0B7ZT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 052c400c7
Firmware Version: CC4C
User Capacity:    1,500,301,910,016 bytes [1.50 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Nov  9 21:38:42 2016 CET

==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive is available,
see the following Seagate web pages:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223651en

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  625) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 209) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   107   091   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       13530088
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   095   095   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       5
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   082   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       169205210
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   078   078   000    Old_age   Always       -       19694
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       5
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       543
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       5 5 5
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   053   041   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 47 (7 6 59 27 0)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   047   059   000    Old_age   Always       -       47 (0 27 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   099   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       18785h+58m+38.071s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       114597464908825
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       161059093725236

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 351 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 351 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19688 hours (820 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:23.550  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:23.528  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 28 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:23.528  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:23.516  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:23.516  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 350 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19688 hours (820 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 58 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:18.898  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:18.299  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:18.299  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:18.299  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:18.298  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 349 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19688 hours (820 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:15.382  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:14.302  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:14.300  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:14.297  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+23:45:14.295  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 348 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19677 hours (819 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+13:00:41.477  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+13:00:41.477  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+13:00:41.477  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+13:00:41.476  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+13:00:41.476  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 347 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 19675 hours (819 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 08 95 49 0b  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0b499508 = 189371656

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+11:11:11.868  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+11:11:11.867  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+11:11:11.867  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+11:11:11.867  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 18 ff ff ff 4f 00  24d+11:11:11.867  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1291         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your hard disk is failing. The log entry `Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed` is quite self-explanatory.